# Estimate gas fees for smart contract function call with Ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, gas-price, gas-estimate

Let's say you have a function in your smart contract, like:

```
function saveUser(address newUser) public {
    // Saving user
}
```

How can we estimate, with Ethers.js, what the gas price will be for calling this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must get the estimated gas price to use in an empty transaction:

```
const gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice();
```

Then, get the estimated gas price for your specific transaction, and multiply it by `gasPrice`:

```
const functionGasFees = await contract.estimateGas.saveUser(userAddress);
const finalGasPrice = gasPrice * functionGasFees;
```

Of course, `finalGasPrice` will never be exactly equal to the actual gas price you will end up paying, but it is a close enough estimate.

Comment: I get a 16-digit number instead of 18 digits when I do this

Comment: Actually, it is a gas amount. Just convert it from hex to decimals and you will see it in a more "natural" way. And gas amount is a simple integer, not wei